# Can I get all instances for a prototype in javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototype

It is easy to get the prototype of an object, but is there any way to get all the instances that has a specific prototype?

Something like this:

```
var allAnimals = Animal.prototype.getInstances();
```

One could write custom code to keep track of instantiated objects, but I'm interested in whether there is any build-in method for this.

Comment: You have to do it explicitly in the class. Classes don't automatically maintain a list of all instances.

Comment: That's a memory leak.

Comment: You could take a heap snapshot (v8 let's you do this) and then inspect. Ideally you would just implement object tracking in a base constructor.

Comment: @SLaks not if you explicitly destroy them as well. If you let instances go out of scope without doing so you will have a leak.

Answer (score 0):

you can get instances that have created on window like this

```
    var o = [];
    (for i in window){
        if(window[i] instanceof Animal) o.push(window[i]);
    }
```

but this code, doesn't get instances which have not been created on window...
you can create a method on `Animal` to create instance from that, and save it in a collection:

```
+function () {

    var AnimalInstances = [];

    Animal = function (flag) {
       if (!flag) throw new Error("Invalid Instantiation");
    };

    Animal.Create = function () {
       var o = new Animal(true);
       AnimalInstances.push(o);
       return o;
    };

    Animal.GetInstances = function () {
       return AnimalInstances;
    };

}();
```

or :

```
+function () {

    var AnimalInstances = [];

    Animal = function () {
        AnimalInstances.push(this);
    }

    Animal.GetInstances = function () {
        return AnimalInstances;
    };
}();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
function A(f){
    this.field = f;
    A.instances.push(this);
}

A.instances = [];
```

so after

```
var one = new A(10), two=new A('123');
```

in `A.instances` will contain two created objects